# Do dynamic web pages always contain content-length field in HTTP header?

Tags: php, asp.net, http

Do dynamic pages like CGI, PHP, ASP, SSI always contain content-length field in the HTTP headers. If not why? Please provide links to webpages hosted on servers which don't include the Content-Length field in the headers. I want to see it first hand.

Comment: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.13 as well as http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.4. Not entirely sure if all languages abide by these rules though bit it gives you a good insight into when it will be left out

Comment: @TBohnen.jnr: So, even if the server does not provide the content length is it still possible for all transfer-encodings for the client to know if it has received the complete request?

Comment: I can't definitely say yes but I think it is safe to assume so for the most part. I've had problems in the past with php and asp.net web services where the content-length in the header and the actual content length does not match but that is a different story :-)

Comment: "Some http servers (cgi programs, to be more precise) send out bogus Content-Length headers" - http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/HTTP-Options.html

Answer (score 4):

Per RFC 2616:

> In HTTP, it SHOULD be sent whenever
>   the message's length can be determined
>   prior to being transferred,

It is often the case that the length cannot be determined beforehand. If you want to check out headers, try `curl -I http://www.example.com`. You'll quickly see that some sites do and some sites don't.

Comment: the should in an RFC means a particular thing. If you've not read RFC's before, take a moment to read the bit at the top where they explain the difference between should/must/etc

Answer (score 1):

I think that pages **NOT need always to send their content-length.**

From the browser side, if browser knows the content-length can show the loading bar, or else just wait to see the "end of the file". If you send a file is better to sent the content-length or else user can not see this loading bar and can't be sure that the file is fully loaded. But if you just have a page, the browser just load until gets the end.

**The reason is that some pages can create their content while they send their data on the client.** This way user no need to wait too much to see the first data coming.

This [Dogs](http://www.mytail.gr/el/PetShop.aspx) page is an example. Also amazon did not send the content-length on most page for the same reason.

The page is flush the data after find the first item, and then is flush the data time to time, so the user not need to spend time waiting for the program first find them all, then calculate the size of the page, and then start sending the data.